# Error with FMDB - unknown column name

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, select, fmdb

I am trying to use a `NSMutableArray` to show some data from my sqlite database in my tableview.

When I use `AssetDesc` as my cell text I can see my description from my sqlite database in my `UITableCell`. So I know everything is working okay.

However when I use AssetName as my cell text I get a sqlite error saying:

```
Warning: I could not find the column named 'AssetName'.
```

If I change this line:

```
customer.assetName = [results stringForColumn:@"AssetName"];
```

like this:

```
customer.assetName = [results stringForColumn:@"AssetDesc"];
```

It works so it has to be something in my database but I cannot pin point it.

But I am sure that that is in my asset table. This makes so sense to me. below is a picture of my database and code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getCustomers
{
    NSMutableArray *customers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];

    [db open];

    FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM asset"];

    while([results next])
    {
        Customer *customer = [[Customer alloc] init];

        customer.assetId = [results intForColumn:@"AssetID"];
        customer.assetName = [results stringForColumn:@"AssetName"];
        customer.assetDesc = [results stringForColumn:@"AssetDesc"];

        [customers addObject:customer];

    }

    [db close];

    return customers;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomerCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Customer *customer = [self.customers objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",customer.assetName]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",customer.assetDesc]];

    return 
}
```

[image]

Comment: When you debugged this, what were the keys in `[results resultDictionary]`?

Comment: Just a side note: You don't open and close the database between requests, you create a query, then close the query when you're done enumerating it

Comment: 2013-06-01 23:22:39.840 [3759:907] Dict: (
    "<Customer: 0x1f5bfda0>",
    "<Customer: 0x1f5bfeb0>",
    "<Customer: 0x1f5bff20>"
)

Comment: Is that what you mean by keys?

Comment: @RedDeFine Unless those are the keys in the `NSDictionary` returned by `[results resultDictionary]` (which they appear to not be, this looks like your `customers` array) then no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I actually had to delete my app off my device and run it again. It was taking reference to the database stored in the documents directory.

I thought it it was taking reference to the dataabase in my Xcode project.

When I deleted the app off the device and installed it again it obviously deleted the files in my documents directory.